# WinPCAP And Non-promiscuous compatible mode?

Tags: winpcap

I've heard that winpcap can work on Non-promiscuous wireless adapters. Is this true?

Is it worth the trouble to work around or should you just use Ethernet if available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true, but it's a headache. When working with WINPCAP, Ethernet is much less troubled area.